# QSqlTableModel и таблица с одинарной кавычкой (MS SQL)

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет в базе данных присутствуют таблицы, которые содержат одинарные кавычки. Таблицы содержащие кавычку в названии не выгружают данные посредством метода:

```
QSqlTableModel::select();
```

Не могу понять как с ними работать. Пробовал решать проблему различными способами, например

```
QString tableName = "My'Table"; // условное название таблицы
//1 tableName.replace("'", "''"); // "My''Table" Данный способ не работает
//2 tableName = QString("[%1]").arg(tableName); "[My'Table]" //Тоже не работает 
tableModel.setTable(tableName);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способы обойти проблему или же придется редактировать название всех таблиц?

Comment: Переименовать следует в любом случае

Comment: Поясните в чем состоит поблема.

Comment: @Cerbo Проблема состоит в том, что  QSqlTableModel не подгружает данные из таблиц, в наименовании которых присутствует кавычка

Comment: Подключение к базе есть? Таблицы без кавычек вы читаете?

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае советую избегать использования кавычек в названиях баз, таблиц и полей. Потому что запрос к такой таблице будет сложнее сформировать. Потому что стандартный вариант

```
INSERT INTO My'Table (field) VALUES(value);
```

не сработает, так как будет не хватать закрывающей кавычки. Добавление закрывающей кавычки (как у вас) тоже не сработает, потому что несоответствие имени, неправильный синтаксис и прочее.

Единственное, что можно сделать:

```
INSERT INTO "My'Table" (field) VALUES(value);
```

Но кавычки в названиях это плохой тон. Как и пробелы и кириллица.

Comment: Проблем с запросами нет, единственная проблема заключается в QSqlTableModel. Такая модель не позволяет выводить информацию собственным запросом. Я раньше работал с данным посредством QSqlQueryModel и прекрасно избегал всех кавычек, но как потребовалось редактировать данные на конкретной строке, принял решение использовать TableModel.

Comment: Вам так сильно нужны эти кавычки? Правда, лучше уберите. Это пока у вас всего одна проблема. Лишние кавычки в SQL ни к чему хорошему не приведут

Comment: Ну, если простого решения не найду, то буду придерживаться вашего совета и избавлюсь от всех кавычек, благодарю!